# unprotected access to my dropbox acount

Tags: dropbox

When I click on the dropbox icon on my desktop, the "recently changed" window opens up.  On that window there is a link to dropbox.com  If I click on the link it immediately opens my account information, folders, documents, profile, security, etc...
Anyone at work who clicks on the icon in my computer can, apart from having total access to my files, change my password and thus leave me out of my own dropbx account.
Is there a way to prevent this, such as requiring the input of my password before opening my files?

Answer (score 2):

No, Dropbox does not offer this as a feature. Just lock your workstation when you leave your seat. If you are using Windows, the shortcut key is Windows + L

Answer (score 0):

They cannot change your password. This would require knowing your password because dropbox asks for the old password before allowing a new password

As for blocking this it it is difficult but possible as far as I can tell. I believe that if you were to block access to the url https://www.dropbox.com/desktop_login on your computer it would prevent dropbox from auto logging you in.

How dropbox works is it creates a temporary HTML file in your temp folder with this content in it. http://pastebin.com/34F8W4bj (I have removed the nonce and user id but everything else is there.) As far as I can tell blocking https://www.dropbox.com/desktop_login should work but I do not have a way to do so at hand. If not then somebody better than I at html will have to look over the file to see what has to be blocked.

Comment: If you block access, doesn't that also mean you block access to your own files on Dropbox.com?

Comment: If you block dropbox.com yes. I don't think that blocking the specific url above would mess with anything else but I am kinda guessing. It is not used in a browser based login as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thank you guys.  I can't get into  https://www.dropbox.com/desktop_login to try to block access.

Comment: Its true that the old password is needed before changing it, but its very disconcerting to have Dropbox open directly into my acount page.  It would be better if it opened into the generic sign-up page.